# Do I need gnome on my PC with 12.04LTS to install gtk themes?

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

I was just asking if I need gnome installed on my PC for me to install GTK themes......on UBUNTU 12.04LTS.

Comment: You are already using gnome, do not confuse with gnome-shell

Comment: Ubuntu 12.03 LTS uses Unity, which in turn uses Gnome. Therefore, Gnome (not to be confused with `gnome-shell`, is already installed. So, you should be fine as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, GTK themes only require... GTK. However, "themes" are designed for specific environments, and you might get a partial result if you do not have GNOME installed. On Ubuntu 12.04, you have basic GNOME, which allows you to install and configure GTK themes. You may need the `gnome-tweak-tool`.